# Weights on equivariant cohomology?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, equivariant

Let $X$ be a quasi-projective variety over the complex numbers, equipped with an action of a linear algebraic group $G$.

Is there a natural mixed Hodge structure on its equivariant cohomology?

Is it pure if $X$ is smooth projective?

What if we ask the analogous question for $l$-adic equivariant cohomology for varieties over finite fields?

More generally is there a formalism of "mixed equivariant derived categories" such that the six functors have the expected effects on weights?

Answer (score 9):

The answer to the first question is yes. Although the words "equivariant cohomology" don't appear there, this goes back to Deligne's Hodge III, since he defines the mixed Hodge structure on a simplicial variety and you can define the Borel construction simplicially in the usual way (via the resolution with $X$, $G \times X$, $G \times G \times X$, and so on). In particular he proves that $H^\bullet(BG)$ is pure of Tate type. If $G$ is connected, then there is a  spectral sequence
$$H^p(BG) \otimes H^q(X) \implies H^{p+q}_G(X).$$
If $X$ is smooth and projective this must therefore degenerate immediately for weight reasons and so the equivariant cohomology of smooth projective varieties is very simple: $H^\bullet_G(X) \cong H^\bullet(X) \otimes H^\bullet(BG)$. In particular the answer to your second question is also yes.

I would imagine that there is a suitable theory of "six functors" for simplicial varieties as well, but I don't know the literature well enough to say anything meaningful or give a reference.

Answer (score 4):

In the $\ell$-adic setting a reference would be Laszlo-Olsson's papers on six operations for Artin stacks:

http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0512097

http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0603680

http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0606175

Also see:

http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.5948

Regarding mixed equivariant derived categories in the Hodge sense, as far as I know there isn't any canonical reference in the literature for this. However, I claim that the Bernstein-Lunts approach (for $X/G$, $G$ linear algebraic) works just fine for mixed Hodge modules (or even $\ell$-adic coefficients, but I am more comfortable with the mixed Hodge setting so not quite as sure about $\ell$-adic). The point is that Bernstein-Lunts mainly just use the six operations in their approach. So everything goes through formally in the same way for mixed Hodge modules. The only place where you might worry is something funny happening with weights. However, there is no problem if all your approximation spaces are algebraic (hence the linear algebraic requirement) and all pushforwards are along proper (algebraic) maps and pullbacks are along smooth (in the algebraic sense) maps.

I remember going through things carefully for $B\backslash G/B$ a couple of years ago. Many of these checks are also done in O. Schnurer's thesis. A condensed/article version of the latter can be found here:

http://arxiv.org/abs/0809.4785

I would also suggest just asking Wolfgang.

I do not know what the state of the art in defining mixed motivic sheaves at the moment is.

Some comments not directly related to the question (but I am reading between the lines and assuming this is where you are coming from Jan): As far as graded representation theory type applications go, the desire for a mixed equivariant derived category usually manifests itself in trying to prove splitting of some sequences, purity/formality type results, and/or to get a grading on Ext-spaces. In each of these situations one can avoid having to invoke a high powered theory of mixed equivariant categories by just working on an approximation space and the mixed (non-equivariant) derived category on this space (we are just unwinding the Bernstein-Lunts approach/Borel construction). I would claim that often even working with a mixed (non-equivariant) derived category can be avoided, since usually the only way one has of getting a handle on Ext-spaces is by interpreting them as cohomology of some space, or a convolution algebra formalism, or using a suitable fibre functor (I am thinking along the lines of Soergel bimodules, Geometric Satake, etc.). So as long as you know there is a functorial mixed structure on cohomology groups you can get away without explicitly invoking mixed categories. Having said that, there is one caveat: coming from the graded representation theory perspective, mixed sheaves offer the opportunity to impose gradings in a functorial way (note: Ext-groups in the mixed derived category are ordinary vector spaces, it is Ext-groups in the non-mixed derived category that inherit mixed structures via realization).  I don't know how one can (in general) cheat to get these mixed strucures on Ext-spaces that behave functorially. In special situations you can get by via devices like Soergel bimoules, working with $\mathbb{C}^*$-coherent sheaves on cotangent bundles, etc. But these are replacements that require a lot of extra work (often worth it for characteristic $p$ applications). In characteristic $0$ the conceptual approach still would be to go through mixed categories. Of course, getting gradings this way is not at all a triviality: a grading corresponds to having split Tate structures which can be quite difficult to prove (eg. I don't know how see directly that Ext between Vermas, in just the ordinary $G/B$ case is split Tate). In representation theory type settings, there is the (somewhat mysterious) phenomenon that intersection cohomology has a basis given by algebraic cycles (I am thinking Geometric Satake, fibres of the Bott-Samelson resolution etc.). As Wolfgang would (probably) say, if we had a fully functional theory of motivic sheaves all the pain would go away!

A comment on Dan Peterson's answer:  I am not sure about a 6 functor formalism for simplicial varieties. There is a brief discussion in Bernstein-Lunts about some of the difficulties in defining six functors and proving their properties in this setting (I don't remember the precise section).

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer! One problem when working with approximations is, that you need to construct them. For example I would not know how to generalize O. Schnurer's thesis to the $P\G/Q$ case since I don't see how to construct the relevant approximations. Also approximations involve choices and choices usually lead to trouble in the long run. 

Comment: I have looked into the other references you suggest and one thing I am missing (though it could be hidden somewhere, I don't understand them very well...) would be the formula $f_!=f_∗$ for proper $f$. Without it, I can't even deduce that $H_G(pt)$ is pure. Do you know if $f_!=f_∗$ is in there or follows easily? 

Comment: Regarding choice of approximation: say $X$ was the $G$-variety; if $V_k'$ and $V_k''$ are both approximations for (the classifying space) for $G$ then so is $V_k = V_k' \times V_k''$. Pulling back along $G\backslash (X\times V_k) \to G\backslash (X\times V_k')$ and similarly for $V_k''$ should give an equivalence showing that your category doesn't depend on the approximation. (I think I am just remembering the argument from Bernstein-Lunts, sorry am traveling right now so can't be more comprehensive).

Comment: Regarding pushforward: so we are given a proper equivariant map $f\colon X\to Y$, then the pushforwards $f_!$ and $f_*$ are basically going to be a family of pushforwards (on the approximations) given by base change. Each of these will be proper, so $f_* = f_!$. Am I missing/misunderstanding something?

Comment: I should add that I am assuming above that the approximations being used above (this is relevant for the argument showing that choice of approximation is irrelevant and nothing messes with weights) is smooth.

Comment: Regarding constructing approximations: if we are limiting ourselves to linear algebraic groups, then it suffices to have then for $GL_n$. Take the $k$-th approximation to be the Steifel variety of $n$-tuples of independent vectors in $\mathbb{C}^{n+k}$. 

Comment: Finally, regarding Olaf's thesis: much more is done there than just checking that the mixed equivariant derived category makes sense and behaves. There (if I remember correctly), one sets up a Hodge package to get formality of the $Ext$ algebra. For this one needs (approximations) to projectives, Hodge structures on them etc. The construction of projectives is inductive in the style of Beilinson-Ginzburg-Soergel. Again if I remember correctly, basically a compatible family of projectives on each approximation is constructed.  (contd. below)

Comment: (contd. 1) In this process for nothing to blow up in your face it becomes convenient to at least have each strata being affine and contractible. All of this is not necessary if the goal is just to have a well behaved (minus formality) mixed equivariant derived category. If you are interested in generalizing Olaf's thesis, I basically don't know how one would proceed if the orbits admit non trivial equivariant local systems. Once more the ideal person to ask would be Wolfgang. He has surely thought a lot about the Harish-Chandra situation

Comment: I seem to have slipped under the rug that $G\backslash(X\times V_k)$ is a well behaved variety. I am not so sure about this. I think additional hypothesis are required. I would have to think a bit more about this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed discussion! By approxiamtions, I meant nice approximations, called "ABC" Olaf. Their most crucial property is, that they admit a nice stratification, such that the derived category of perverse sheaves equals the constructible derived category.

It suffices to construct them for the group acting on a point and as you said, they are given by Stiefel varieties, if $G=GL_n$. Now the problem is, if you just take a subgroup of $GL_n$ and let it act on the Stiefel varieties, the resulting approximation won't be nice!



Comment: For $f_*=f_!$ you are right, but only in the case where $f$ is a map between two $G$-varieties. However in the most interesting examples this is not the case! For example the relevant map for equivariant cohomology $X//G\rightarrow pt$ does NOT fit into this framework!

Comment: Regarding ABC approximations: This is exactly the issue I was referring to when I mentioned things blowing up if you have non-trivial local systems on the orbits/strata. However, just to clarify: (working non-equivariantly) the constructs le derived category is always equivalent to the derived category of perverse sheaves. Things screw up only if you fix a stratification. Then the constructive (with respect to the fixed stratification) is not necessarily equivalent to the derived category of perverse sheaves smooth along that stratification. The ABC stratifications essentially require (contd.)

Comment: (contd. 2) that $H^1$ and $H^2$ of strata vanish (basically to give an induction that Ext groups in your triangulated categories coincide). This sort of situation excludes several cases (for instance the Harish-Chandra case) when you have non trivial local systems. This isn't proof but I think some jiggling of this line of argument will show that nice ABC approximations can't exist if you have non trivial equivariant local systems. It would be nice to get around this, since this is basically the 'obstruction' to construct a tilting generator (with Hodge package) to get equivariant formality

Comment: Regarding the discussion on proper maps: What is your favorite (non trivial) example of a proper map of stacks $X/G \to pt/G$ that doesn't come from a proper $X \to pt$ and such that the induced maps on approximations aren't proper? Sorry I am not very fluent with stacks.

Comment: The map $X/G\rightarrow pt/G$ is easy, while $X/G\rightarrow pt$ is more problematic. For example suppose $X=pt$. Then the push forward along the first map is just the identity functor, while push forward along the second map is taking equivariant hypercohomology (of a point).